# can not use 'OnComplete' client event with telerik mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

i use telerik mvc release 2011.2.712,Jquery 1.4.1
the problem is :
when i use clientEvent `OnComplete` or `OnCommand` i get error

> Unknown method 'OnComplete' of 'telerik.web.mvc.UI.fluent.GridClientEventsBuilder'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older version and you need to upgrade.